# Использование переменных связывания с динамическим SELECT..INTO в EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Где могут быть использованы переменные связывания в динамическом SQL запросе в PL/SQL?

Например, мне известно, что так будет работать:

```sql
declare
    jobId varchar2 (16) := 'IT_PROG';
    res number;
begin
    execute immediate '
        select count (*) 
        from hr.employees where job_id = :b1'
    into res using jobId;
end;
/
```

А могли ли вы подсказать, возможно ли использовать переменные связывания вот так:

```sql
declare
    jobId varchar2 (16) := 'IT_PROG';
    res number;
begin
    execute immediate '
        select count (*) into :b1 
        from hr.employees where job_id = :b2'
    using out res, jobId;
end;
/
```

Заметьте, это `SELECT..INTO` запрос и переменная связывания стоит в `INTO` клаузуле.

В настоящее время не могу проверить на реальной БД, а вопрос несколько мучает меня. Читая документацию по PL/SQL, не нахожу ответа или примера подобного применения.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/7816402/6571020

Answer (score 2):

Заключите запрос в диинамический `BEGIN-END` блок:

```sql
declare
    jobId varchar2 (16) := 'IT_PROG';
    res number;
begin
    execute immediate '
    begin
        select count (*) into :b1 
        from hr.employees where job_id = :b2;
    end;'
    using out res, jobId;
end;
/
```

Согласен с другими, что первый метод - чисто динамический SQL, намного лучше, чем второй - динамический PL/SQL блок. Динамический PL/SQL очень редко встречается и практически в нем нет необходимости. Не заметил какого-то отличия в производительности между этими двумя методами, но предпологаю, что PL/SQL метод будет в некоторых случаях немного медленней.

Динамический PL/SQL метод в данном случае создаст 3 переменные связывания:
2 для PL/SQL блока (то есть, не видимых в представлении `V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE`), и одну для SQL запроса. Это может значительно осложнить отладку и затруднить поиск ошибок.

Источники: [ответ @JonHeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816651/6571020), [комментарий к ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816402/using-bind-variables-with-dynamic-select-into-clause-in-pl-sql#comment9546721_7816651) (*прим. ред.* - включил комментарий в ответ).

Answer (score 2):

Второй вариант с `SELECT..INTO` совершенно неверен потому, что:

1. Цитата [из офф. док. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8):

   > Note: If dynamic_sql_statement is a **SELECT** statement, and you omit both into_clause and bulk_collect_into_clause, then execute_immediate_statement **never executes**.

   Без `INTO` клаузулы в `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` запрос `SELECT` **никогда не будет выполнен**.
2. Хотя запрос вида `SELECT..INTO` может быть выполнен чисто в SQL контексте, но `INTO` 
   клаузула, включая переменную(ые) связывания в ней, будут проигнорированны при выполнении:

   ```sql
   SQL> select 1 num into :b1 from dual;

          NUM
   ----------
            1

   SQL> print b1
   SP2-0552: Bind variable "B1" not declared.
   ```
3. Имеет ли смысл заключить запрос в `BEGIN-END`, чтобы он стал динамическим PL/SQL блоком, [ответ в данной теме уже дан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1075855/217579).